# JavaScript custom button in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I created one custom button on the standard layout in Salesfoce which calls the apex code to call the java webservice. Now the problem is once the user clicks on the button I should disable the button or I should blur the screen until I process the request. How do I achieve this functionality with JavaScript?Any samples would be appreciated.

Thanks alot guys

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you're calling will have access to "this" variable that will represent the button being clicked.

You can test code below before adding it to your button. Try it in JavaScript console of "Edit" page for example

```
var fakeThis = document.getElementsByName('save')[0];
var oldValue = this.value;
fakeThis.setAttribute('class', 'btnDisabled');
fakeThis.value = 'Processing...';
fakeThis.disabled = true;
```

Class 'btnDisabled' is what makes Salesforce buttons appear grayed out and "flat" (pressed). When you're done - restore old values

```
fakeThis.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
fakeThis.value = oldValue;
fakeThis.disabled = false;
```

Comment: if({!Security_Principal__c.Active__c} == false){
alert('Security Principle is already deactivated');
}
else{
window.open("/apex/TerminateScredentials?Pid={!Security_Principal__c.Id}","_self");
} this is code for the button.Can you share your thoughts basing on my code. thanks alot